# Is the Trefoil knot isotopic to the unknot (torus) in ambient $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I am watching this video on topology:

https://youtu.be/CJBfpvWBmSs

One of the claims is in an earlier video:

https://youtu.be/CZqeAC07_UE?t=1037

Suppose we have manifolds with dimensions $L$ and $K$ in ambient with a dimension $M$. If $K + L - M = -1$, then the manifolds must cross to "change sides". If $K + L - M < -1$, then the crossing can be avoided. The meaning of "changing sides" is left somewhat undefined in the video.

Consequently, [in one of his later examples](https://youtu.be/CJBfpvWBmSs?t=238), the lecturer says that to untie the Trefoil knot, you need the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^6$ (one of the students also gives the answer 6).

However, it seems to me that it is possible to untie a Trefoil knot in $\mathbb{R}^4$. If you pull out one part of the knot into the direction of the 4-th dimension, then you can obviously circumvent the adjacent part without crossing it. In fact, this is observed in one of the comments below the video too.

**Is this intuition correct? Can you untie the Trefoil knot in 4 dimensions?**

If it is, then according to [this definition](https://youtu.be/CJBfpvWBmSs?t=451), the Trefoil knot is isotopic to the unknot in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

EDIT:

When I said "Trefoil knot", I actually meant the following 2-dimensional surface:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, all (1-dimensional) knots can be unknotted in $\mathbb{R}^4$, exactly as you argue. A nice visualization is to let the fourth dimension be color-then you can accomplish the necessary crossings by turning, say, the lower strand red and the upper blue. This actually agrees with the inequality given in your lectures.

Comment: Here's a possibly silly question. What then plays the proper role of a knot in dimension 4?

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about topology, so sorry if maybe my question is not precise enough. When I said "Trefoil knot" I meant a 2-dimensional manifold, like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot#/media/File:Blue_Trefoil_Knot.png

Isn't that a 2-dimensional knot?

Comment: In other words, to say that 1-dimensional knots can be unknotted in $\mathbb{R}^4$ seems consistent with his Theorem 2. What about 2-dimensional knots - can at least some of them be unknotted in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Embedded surfaces, in particular embedded 2-spheres. There's a [great book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540210405) on this.

Comment: @axel22 If your surface is the boundary of a small neighborhood of a 1-D knot in $\Bbb R^3$, those are unknotted in $\Bbb R^4$ by more or less the same argument.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, that's what I thought - thanks for confirming that!

But then, by Thm 2 from the lecture, e.g. two entangled tori (i.e. manifolds of dimension 2) have an overflow $-1$ in an ambient $\mathbb{R}^5$ (i.e. $2 + 2 - 5 = -1$), and consequently must cross. This seems to be a contradiction, because, if they can be unknotted  in $\mathbb{R}^4$, then obviously they can be unknotted in $\mathbb{R}^5$ too. It seems that the Thm 2 is either stated incorrectly, or I'm misinterpreting it.

Comment: I didn't watch the video. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @axel22 I think I get the confusion. Mike gave you an example of a "2-dimensional knot" that can be unknotted in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but more or less by definition this means that it's not *entangled*-it's a 2-dimensional unknot. I think the theorem is fine. In general, moving a 2D surface across another 2D surface will use up 5 degrees of freedom, so there will generally be some collision points in $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: @axel22 The trefoil knot picture in Wikipedia is misleading. You can shrink the diameter of the "thread" making up that knot to zero to see that this should really be seen as a 1-dimensional knot: there's only one degree of freedom in moving along the knot itself. More formally, the trefoil knot is naturally seen as the image of a continuous map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. My best guess is that your lecturer was confused confused. A legitimate knotted surface will involve a (hollow) torus or sphere that, viewed in 3D, appears to pass in and out of itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining this. I understand now - the knot is 1-dimensional entity (in fact, it's defined like that here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory#Knot_equivalence). About the theorem, I think that it applies to planes, and not arbitrary surfaces, and that it should not have been used in that example to conclude that $\mathbb{R}^6$ is the smallest ambient for isotopy.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @MikeMiller ! I suspected it was a 2D surface, but wasn't sure.

Comment: There are actually not any 'really' knotted tori in $S^3$, in the sense that one of the sides of the torus is always a (knotted) solid torus; in particular any $T^2$ in $S^3$ is truly unknotted in $S^4$. Higher genus surfaces can have very knotty embeddings in $S^3$ (neither side extends to a handlebody), and sometimes they also don't unknot in $S^4$.

Comment: There is the application of that theorem in Lecture 7 again. The lecturer claims that you need $\mathbb{R}^5$ to "remove" the circle from the surface of a torus without intersecting the torus with the circle. The argument is summarized in the 1.5 min of the video, starting here: https://youtu.be/AgUGxqeVFZE?t=1075 . But by all the arguments in this thread, $\mathbb{R}^4$ should be sufficient. Who is wrong here?